# Find a basis for a vector space of n differentiable functions.

Tags: vector-spaces

The vector space is V, and is generated by the set of vectors $S=\{cos^{2}(x),sin^{2}(x),cos(2x)\}$. I have been working on for the past couple of hours to demonstrate that the set is linearly dependent, and I got it through the Wronskian.

However, I could not find a basis for that vector space.

Any ideas? Is the Wronskian useful in this case?

Comment: Is the set of $n$ vectors or $3$ vectors?

Comment: I guess you mean $\sin^2$.

Comment: The set has 3 vectors.

Comment: I have used the plus/minus theorem, to find a linearly independent set that generates vector space. This is the process:

$sin^2(x)=acos(2x) \iff x=arcsin(\sqrt\frac{a}{1+a})$
$\forall a \in R$

removing $cos^{2}(x)$ from the generator set and using the identity $cos(2x)=1-sin^2(x)$. Where I got that, the only solution that satisfies the equation is $x = \pi + 2\pi n , n\in R$ and $a = 0$. Therefore the system is linearly independent, so the set $S'=\{sin^2(x),cos(2x)\}$ is a base. 

Although I don't know if the result is correct, or my reasoning is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

$S$ is linearly dependent because
$$\cos 2x = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x.$$
So, $S \setminus \{ \cos 2x \}$ is a basis for that vector space (check the independence now).